# jQuery click handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I can't get the following function to work.

On click of class .image, content in 3 divs (gallerytext, image, and thumbset)  is to be replaced. I have been trying to get this to work for days now and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
     // Init load 
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var $doc = $(document.body);


        var text = $('#gallerytext1').html();  //blank divs are filled with content on page load 
        $('#gallerytext').html(text);
        var thumbset = $('#thumbset1').html();
        $('#thumbset').html(thumbset);  
        $('#image').html('<img src="images/edwards1.jpg" border="0"/>');


    //click handler
       $doc.on("click",".image",function(){

        var image=$(".image").attr("rel"); 
        var imid=$(".image").attr("data");
        var text=$('#gallerytext'+imid).html();
        var thumbset=('#thumbset'+imid).html();

        $('#debug').html(imid);

        $('#gallerytext').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#gallerytext').html(text);
        $('#thumbset').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#thumbset').html(thumbset);
        $('#image').hide();                 
        $('#image').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
        return false;


      });
  });
```

The initial content loads just fine but I cannot get the click handler to work. Objects with the class .image are formatted as such:

```
<a href="#" rel="images/edwards2.jpg" data="1" class="image image2"><img src="images/edwardsthumb2.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
```

Any assistance would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These are probably your problematic lines:

```
var image=$(".image").attr("rel"); 
var imid=$(".image").attr("data");
```

`$(".image")` selects *all* of the elements with a class of `image`. You want just the one that was clicked, so use `this` to refer to it:

```
var image = $(this).attr("rel"); 
var imid = $(this).attr("data");
```

Also, don't make up custom attributes like `data`. HTML5 introduced `data-` attributes which are used to store custom data types, so use them:

```
data-number="1"
```

And you can access it with the `.data()` method:

```
var imid = $(this).data('number');
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used "this" but the click is still not working. Noted in regards to "data", I will amend.

Comment: @Sceneman: You'll have to be more specific than that. Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Oh, sorry, as per Chrome console I am getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' js.js 15. This will be referring to this line here: $doc.on("click",".image",function(){...

Comment: @Sceneman try doing some sanity checking then. If the console says ```on``` isn't a method, and you know that it should work, then that means there's something wrong with variable ```$doc```. It's possible it could be undefined.

Comment: Thanks, the variable was an issue. I have cleared that error now. The click handler is recognizing clicks now, but .image is coming through as "undefined". I believe 'this' is not reading as intended. I'll keep working on this thanks for the adice.